# Is it possible for a function to know the name of its assignment target?

Tags: r, assign

This is probably impossible but let me try anyway...

Is it possible to write this function?

```
Foo<-function(n){
     X=runif(n)
     write.csv(X,file=paste([the name of the assignment target],".csv",sep="")
    }
```

So that when I do

```
ABC<-Foo(10)
```

It generates 10 random numbers and both store it to the R object ABC and write a csv file called "ABC.csv"?

I know you can do something like this:

```
Foo2<-function(n,name){
        X=runif(n)
        write.csv(X,file=paste(name,".csv",sep=""))
        assign(name,X,envir=.GlobalEnv)
      }
Foo2(10,"ABC")
```

But I would like to use the arrow operator <- because it is the usual syntax in R. So Foo2 really isn't perfect. And of course

```
ABC<-Foo2(10,"ABC")
```

is meaningless because it means typing the name twice.

Answer (score 4):

If we change the syntax somewhat we can do it.  First define:

```
Random <- structure(NA,class="Random")
"$<-.Random" <- function(x, name, value) {
    X <- runif(value)
    write.csv(X, file = paste0(name, ".csv"))
    assign(name, X, parent.frame())
    invisible(x)
}
```

This is used like this:

```
Random$abc <- 3
```

after which `abc` will be a vector of generated numbers and a `abc.csv` file will be written out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can overwrite `<-` but you could make your own binary function `%<-%`

```
Foo <- function(n){
    runif(n)
}

`%<-%` <- function(x, y){
    xname <- as.character(substitute(x))
    assign(xname, y, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    write.csv(y, file = paste0(xname, ".csv"))
}
```

and an example

```
> dir()
character(0)
> ls()
[1] "%<-%" "Foo" 
> x %<-% Foo(3)
> x
[1] 0.1838146 0.6785800 0.3758954
> read.csv("x.csv")
  X         x
1 1 0.1838146
2 2 0.6785800
3 3 0.3758954
```

Comment: I see, so the way of thinking is to modify (or pretend to modify) <- rather than Foo.

Comment: Well `Foo` has no way of knowing what will happen to its output so it has no way of knowing the name of what it is being assigned into (or if it's assigned into anything at all) so if you want to keep the syntax you requested it can't just be a modification to Foo.